# Filtering tuple with custom object, Swift

Tags: swift, tuples

I have a datasource made like this:

```
[(header: String?, cells: [CustomObject])]
```

Lets say customObject as a field `name`.

Now I need to filter my dataSource by `name` given by the searcher text.

How do I filter all elements that contains this given text in my CustomObject name value?

I would have done something like this if I haven't a tuple:

```
filteredDataSource = dataSource.filter({
    return $0.questionTitle.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
})
```

---

UPDATE:

The main datasource is composed like this:

header: Europe
cells: CustomObject("Italy), CustomObject("Germany)...

header: Africa
cells: CustomObject("Congo")...

By filtering with the searched text (For example Italy), the cells are correctly filtered! But the header is not filtered accordingly. So I receive:

header: Africa
cells: CustomObject("italy)

for example...

How do I filter cells with the searchedText and headers accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `compactMap` for this and filter your nested array and return nil if there isn't any match in nested array.

```
let search = searchText.lowercased()
let filteredArray = tupleArray.compactMap({
    let filteredCells = $0.cells.filter({ $0.name.lowercased().contains(search) })
    return filteredCells.isEmpty ? nil : ($0.header, filteredCells)
})
```

Comment: That works great! May I ask: what if each header is connected with some given cells? Lets say I have some headers that are continents and cells are countries. If I filter that way I receive that for example Germany is under Africa header

Comment: @manubrio, If you filter like above it is not changing your header, can you update your question with more details and examples so I can get an idea of what you are asking

Comment: @manubrio In that case issue is in how you are rendering this filtered array in your view. If you print `filteredArray` after you apply the filter it will always print the correct header and cells. You can verify that